# "Technology" is to "technical" as "memory" is to what?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, adjectives, analogy

I'm writing a sentence about the job of the memory and am characterizing absorption with memory. How do I say "memorical absorption" correctly? *Memorial* sounds like a noun...

Comment: It's the first time I've heard *memorical*.

Comment: I suppose technology is to technical more or less as memory is to memorabilia: they are both examples of words derived from the same Latin or Greek root, but with different derivations and completely different meanings. They are only comparable in their incomparability. If you're simply looking for an adjective meaning ‘pertaining to memory’, though, I'd say _memorial_ is your best bet. That or just using ‘memory’ as a noun adjunct (though that might not work with absorption in particular—I don't know what memory/-ial absorption even is).

Comment: By memory are you referring to human or mechanical memory? Human memory, I'd think technical is to technology as memory is to retention. For mechanical memory, I think the word would be state. You could use state in either context, but IMHO it's more mechanical memory. Justification - technology is expression of a technical concept. State is an expression of a memory concept.

Comment: How about "retentive"?

Comment: "mental"? Or is that too simple?

Answer (score 12):

The term "mnemonic" is sometimes used in academic writing to mean "of or pertaining to memory" (e.g. "mnemonic processing").

Comment: Perfect choice.